# The option to add a tag should be visible at the top of individual tag pages

Tags: feature-request, tags

Right now the "Add to Favorites" option for a tag is really far down the page - even on an individual tag's info page. When I visit and individual [tag's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), I expect the option to add that tag to my favorites to appear in the info box for the tag (or if not there, somewhere nearby.... not hidden below the fold).

[image]